# select list change selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I'm using http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#dropdown-menu
for my select lists.
This generates a dropdown in the form of an ul with list items in it and hides the select list.
I thought that when you select a list item in the ul this will select that specific option in the select list.
But it doesn't so I'm trying to get this to work.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm dropdown_select dropdown_select_ratio" id="aspect_dropdown" data-dropdownjs="true" style="display: none;">
  <option value="4:3">4:3</option>
  <option value="3:2">3:2</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="16:9">16:9</option>
  <option value="17:9">17:9</option>
  <option value="21:9">21:9</option>
</select>
```

This will be generated beneath it and hides the above select list:

```
<div class="dropdownjs">
    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control input-sm dropdown_select dropdown_select_ratio focus">
    <ul placement="bottom-left" style="max-height: 748px;">
        <li value="4:3" tabindex="-1">4:3</li>
        <li value="3:2" tabindex="-1" class="selected">3:2</li>
        <li value="16:9" selected="selected" class="" tabindex="-1">16:9</li>
        <li value="17:9" tabindex="-1">17:9</li><li value="21:9" tabindex="-1">21:9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jquery that I'm using to select the option in the selectlist:

```
$('.dropdownjs ul li').click(function(){
    var selectedvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    var selected = $(this).parent().parent().prev('.dropdown_select');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(selected);
        $(selected + 'option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $(selected).find("option[value'" + selectedvalue + "']");
    }, 100);
})
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]option:selected
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a space here : `$(selected + ' option:selected').removeAttr('selected');`?

Comment: @D4V1D yes not working either.

Comment: Is the error still remains the same?

Comment: what does `console.log(selected);` ouptut?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes still the same error. Also tried in in jsfiddle.

Comment: @craicerjack [select#aspect_dropdown.form-control.input-sm.dropdown_select.dropdown_select_ratio, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: li.selected, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…] That is the right element.

Comment: Also (still JSFiddling it), you're missing an `=` here : `$(selected).find("option[value='" + selectedvalue + "']");`

Comment: @andredewaard except it looks like `selected` is an array.  `$(selected[0] + 'option:selected').removeAttr('selected');` make any difference?

Comment: @D4V1D Ah yes stupid mistake. But still not working :(

Comment: @Craicerjack Gives another error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement] option:selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm dropdown_select dropdown_select_ratio" id="aspect_dropdown" data-dropdownjs="true" style="display: block;">
  <option value="4:3">4:3</option>
  <option value="3:2">3:2</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="16:9">16:9</option>
  <option value="17:9">17:9</option>
  <option value="21:9">21:9</option>
</select>

<div class="dropdownjs">
    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control input-sm dropdown_select dropdown_select_ratio focus">
    <ul placement="bottom-left" style="max-height: 748px;">
        <li value="4:3" tabindex="-1">4:3</li>
        <li value="3:2" tabindex="-1" class="selected">3:2</li>
        <li value="16:9" selected="selected" class="" tabindex="-1">16:9</li>
        <li value="17:9" tabindex="-1">17:9</li><li value="21:9" tabindex="-1">21:9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.dropdownjs ul li').click(function(){
    var selectedvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    var selected = $('#aspect_dropdown');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(selectedvalue);
        $(selected[0]).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $(selected[0]).val($(selected[0]).find('option[value="' + selectedvalue + '"]').val()).trigger('change');
    }, 100);
})
```

**Working JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/cq9ccc3t/1/

Alter the code I've modified as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! But this kinda works except that i have multiple of this select items on one page that is why i was trying to use: $(this).parent().parent().prev('.dropdown_select'); And it shows the right option but somehow does not add the selected="selected" attribute.

Comment: You are a genius! thanks. Somehow in my project it won't remove the attribute selected but in the Jsfiddle is does. So i will figure that out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Got that to work with: $(selected[0]).find('option').removeAttr('selected')